# get some field of text with sed command

Tags: sed

I have these line:

```
"CN=Michael George\, Jou,OU=External,OU=User,DC=Company,DC=en"
```

I would like to extract these:

```
 Michael George\, Jou
```

I'm trying with sed:

```
grep -i "CN" file | sed "s/CN=\(.*\),\(.*\)/\1/g"
```

But I can't have these result. Could you help me with sed  command? Thanks

Comment: does your `grep` support `-P` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str="CN=Michael George\, Jou,OU=External,OU=User,DC=Company,DC=en" 
echo "${str}" | sed 's/.*CN=\([^=]*\),.*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
Michael George\, Jou
```